# Sort more than 10 numbers in Swift3

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3

I try to sort a String Array with numbers but i dont get the right order.

```
print(alleTouren) // ["1", "3", "2", "5", "15", "4"]

alleTouren = alleTouren.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})                               

print(alleTouren)  // ["1", "15", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

I also tried **alleTouren.sort(by:<)** and **alleTouren.sort()** but i always get back the 15 too early. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You do get the right order: the strings are correctly lexicographically sorted. If you want integer sorting, you'll have to convert them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all strings can be converted to `Int` add the conversion to the closure.

```
var alleTouren = ["1", "3", "2", "5", "15", "4"]
alleTouren = alleTouren.sorted(by: { Int($0)! < Int($1)! })
```

Alternatively use the `compare` function of `String` with `numeric` option which is probably more efficient.

```
alleTouren = alleTouren.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1, options:.numeric) == .orderedAscending} )
```

Comment: I'm curious how this compares with `alleTouren.flatMap(Int.init).sorted.flatMap(String.init)` for performance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you seem to be saying you want to sort them as though they are numbers, but they are strings, so "1", "15", "2"... is correct. You could try converting $0 and $1 to integers and comparing these.

I'm not a Swift expert, but this seems to work:

```
alleTouren = alleTouren.sorted{let s0 = Int($0)
let s1 = Int($1)
return s0! < s1!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i did not test it because the first answer already did his job and looks more easy for me.